# Mixed-effect logistic regression in R - questions

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model

I am new to R, and don't see these questions answered anywhere in documentation (though I could be wrong).

1. I am using the following nomenclature to run my mixed-effects logistic regression, based on instructions from another site:

   `output <- glmer(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + (1 | RE), family = binomial, nAGQ = 10)`
   RE is a factor with several levels.

   This works. But I'm wondering why it's necessary to use the `(1 | RE)` syntax instead of just `DV~IV1+IV2 | RE`.
2. I am running two mixed effects logistic regressions. On one of them I can view the random effects intercepts using `ranef()`. But I get all 0s when I run ranef on the output of the other one. Both regressions/data are ostensibly the same. What do all 0s for the random effects intercepts mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `(1|RE)` specifies that you want the *intercept* to vary randomly across levels of `RE`. You could also specify `(1+IV1|RE)` for example if you wanted the intercept *and* the slope for `IV1` to vary randomly.
2. Perhaps there is no considerable variation in the intercept across `RE` that can be picked up in the second data set. Does the basic fit output (`summary(fitObject)`) suggest no variation on that intercept in the second model?

That's about all that can be said without more information.

Comment: This was enormously helpful. In regards to question 2, I just looked at the `summary()` output for the model, and indeed the variance is 0 and SD 0 for the random effects variable. I'm surprised by this; I think I need to go back and make sure the data in my data matrix is lined up correctly.